CloudFront origin is returning 429 when asking for images with next.js application
Yesterday I deployed my Next.js application on AWS using sts (not amplify because it has cache problem and it was slow because and my application is e-commerce so needs fast as much as possible).
The website has been running well and everything looks fine except for a few pages that have many images.
Every image is optimized for better performance so we have proper caching. Everything is working fine on the caching side as well.
However, sometimes I see that my application receives 429 from /next/images* origin with message:

{"Reason":"ConcurrentInvocationLimitExceeded","Type":"User","message":"Rate Exceeded."}

I am confused what whether I should ask AWS to increase the limit. I do not have Developer Support here.
You can try my application here as well: https://dtjlmuofdvydq.cloudfront.net
A page that has issues: https://dtjlmuofdvydq.cloudfront.net/bachelorette-decorations
I tried asking for help on AWS support (basic not helping).
I tried configuring and changing default settings that comes with sts (enabling and disabling Cloudflare function) but still have the issue.
Amplify is not a solution here because of lack of control and speed.

are you using apigateway or lambda to serve your application ?

i am using lambda. this is shipped by default from sts

I'm not aware of a service sts that's is shipped with lambda ?! any docs or links for it. For ConcurrentInvocationLimitExceeded if it's source is Lambda (check cloudwatch metrics) and check the service quota by default it's 1000 also in cloudfront side check the ttl used for caching this can be tuned to decrese number of requests to your lambda backend

so I am using sts for the next deployment under the hood they use the open-next project to deploy multiple lambda functions and add CloudFront.
open-next project: https://open-next.js.org/
sts: https://docs.sst.dev/start/nextjs
I look look at cloudfront ttl for fine-tuning
BT I am not looking to decrease the request I am looking to increase the limit

Ah ok it's a framework and called SST, I tought it was an AWS service (because AW has an STS service) this is why I was asking. For increasing this limit it should not be so hard you need to open a service quota increase case form AWS console search for Service Quotas and choose Lambda service > request quota increase...

sure will do this
